# How to Fallback to Desktop View When the Mobile View Does Not Exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple configuration switch in web.config to switch between using mobile version vs desktop version of the app. It is a bool flag thats it. Then in the Global.asax file I have the following code:

```
 private void ConfigureMobileViewSwitcher()
        {
            if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Mobile") != null)
            {
                bool isMobile = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mobile"]);

                // only inject the mobile display mode if the switch is set in app settings 
                if (isMobile)
                {   
                    DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
                    {
                        ContextCondition = (context => isMobile)
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that when the mobile switch is true that means use the .Mobile pages and the mobile pages does not exist then it will throw an error instead of switching to the desktop version of the same view.

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page
```

**EXPLANATION IN SIMPLE ENGLISH:**

Basically what I want is that if the mobile view does not exist for certain actions then it will render the desktop versions of that view.

UPDATE:

I checked the DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes collection and on initial launch it contains 2 entries.

```
Index 0 has "Mobile 
Index 1 has "" which I believe is the default 

Then I insert another "Mobile" on Index 0
```

The screenshot below shows more details.

[image]

Here is the actual error:

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page &quot;~/Views/Shared/MainLayout.cshtml&quot;: &quot;head; breadcrumb; banner; leftContent; mainContent&quot;
```

I get the above message when I try to view a page in mobile and that page/view does not exist. But the page exist for the desktop application and the mobile app should just fallback to the desktop view.

Comment: Running in debug, ho many Modes do you have in the provider instance?

Comment: I updated the original question to add more details.

Comment: I can't test right now but if I remember correctly, if the mobile view is not available, it falls back to the 'regular' view. Can you try not to add the new display mode and see if it works? (so you should only have the 2 default modes)

Comment: Thanks! I removed the mode that I was adding manually. But it does not fallback to the desktop view. I am testing using emulation in the chrome browser. It always say that sections are not implemented but they are implemented in the desktop view. Is there a cache issue!

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your controller and view(s) as well as the full error message?

Comment: Updated with error in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you have two Display Modes configured.  Firstly, the DefaultDisplayMode with an empty suffix that will trigger display of your Desktop views (Index.cshtml), then, a second, custom Mobile Display Mode, that will override the Desktop views with the Mobile views, if one exists (Index.Mobile.cshtml).  If a Mobile view doesn't exist, it will fall back to using the Desktop view.

```
public class CustomMobileDisplayMode : DefaultDisplayMode
{
    public CustomMobileDisplayMode() : base("Mobile")
    {
        ContextCondition = httpContext => IsCustomMobile(httpContext);
    }

    private bool IsCustomMobile(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // All mobile devices will trigger the Mobile view
        // Or, if the override setting is in the config
        return httpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice ||
               Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mobile"]);
    }
}
```

Somewhere, during configuration, execute something like the following that will initialise both Display Modes and add them in the correct order.

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Clear();
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new DefaultDisplayMode());
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new CustomMobileDisplayMode());
```