# Invoking Same Name Controller Action for Mobile Devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action called "Detail" which is invoked by the ASP.NET MVC desktop application. Now, I want to invoke a different action with the same name "Detail" but it will only be invoked by the mobile devices like iPhones and Android etc.

Is there any Attribute I can put on the new Detail action with same parameters as the old one which will only be invoked by mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` to create a Mobile-only route matcher:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class RouteMobileActionAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice;
    }
}
```

Then apply it:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{
     // ....
}

[ActionName("Detail")]
[RouteMobileAction]
public ActionResult MobileDetail(int id)
{
     // ....
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

P.S Have you considered using [DisplayModes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn296507.aspx) instead?

Comment: Thanks! I am currently using DisplayModes but the problem is that if the mobile view does not exist then the framework does not fallback on the desktop views. Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794403/how-to-fallback-to-desktop-view-when-the-mobile-view-does-not-exist